# Entity Framework insert error ("The Version field is required.")

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am using Silverlight 4 and RIA services. When I try to insert into my database, I get the following error:

> "Submit operation failed validation. Please inspect Entity.ValidationErrors for each entity in EntitiesInError for more information."

Upon inspecting the ValidationErrors, I see:

> "The Version field is required."

Isn't the Version field updated and maintained by the framework? If so, why is it null? If not, how am I supposed to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug with in Silverlight 4. Hopefully it will be fixed in the final release.

It can be fixed by simply setting `[Entity].Version = new byte[0];`.

Comment: Graham could u please tell me where this line need to add?